# How to find the average percentage of faults detected (APFD) for test cases in open source projects?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, test-coverage, software-quality

I'm practicing test case prioritization techniques. To get real results, I need some metrics for test cases such as the average percentage of faults detected (APFD), APFD per cost, and so on. To to find these data for open source projects?

Note that I have the code and the test cases, however, I'm not sure how to find the history of fault detection for each test case.

Thank you,

Comment: What test engine are you using, how are the test case reports generated? We need some more background on your technology stack to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am using Xcode, but my question is generic (at least this is what I think). I mean where do I get the faults in the previous versions and which test case detected them in that version? should I inject faults randomly in different versions and see which test case detected them?

Comment: If I understood you right, you should use a test case management solution such as [TestLink](http://testlink.org/) to have a proper handling of test cases and from there get your reports done.